# How to add a HTML document into a <div></div> via JavaScript/ JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do I add an HTML doc into a `<div></div>` via JavaScript/ JQuery?

This is what i have so far;

emailBodyInclude.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imports/reset.css" type="text/css" />

    <script>
        // JavaScript
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Using JavaScript/ JQuery, how can I go about removing from a HTML document any declarations of the form of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head></head>
<body></body>
```

So that I be left with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imports/reset.css" type="text/css" />

<script>
    // JavaScript
</script>

<p>Hello world! This is HTML5 Boilerplate.</p>
```

so that I can safely insert what remains into a `<div></div>`

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE:**

emailBodyInclude.html is a String of HTML mail retrieved from a provider, like Yahoo, for example. It is dynamic, and there is no way to tell what the syntax will look like. I would like to include this html document inside another. Inside a `<div class="htmlMail"></div>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../baseCSS/bootStrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">This is a HTML email</div>
    <div class="htmlMail"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you cannot do this with a one liner... extract what you want into java-script and then deleting everything and add back... is probably the best method.

Comment: PS was not me, just up voted, i agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use load for this    http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('.htmlMail').empty().load('emailBodyInclude.html');
```

Comment: I had already tried that, and it doesn't work. Please take a look at my update.

Comment: what didnt work about it?  did you get an error, or did your body just do nothing? see my edit?