# Replace content of DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to dinamically replace the content of a DIV but the only function that I found which can dinamically insert content into a DIV is "append" as per below. However, as you would expect, it doesn't replace the content, but appends it. How can I do it?

```
$("#notification").fadeIn("slow").append('Error!');
```

Comment: yes, see this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602212/how-to-add-a-html-document-into-a-div-div-via-javascript-jquery/33602265#33602265**strong text**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#notification").fadeIn("slow").html('Error!');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in multiple ways using jquery

- `.html( htmlString )` - http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2
- `.replaceWith( newContent )`  -http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/
- `.text( text )` - http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

In vanilla javascript you can just set innerHTML

```
document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML = "Error!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for jquery **.replaceWith()** ? the examples are [here](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

Answer (score 0):

yes, the way you can do that using jquery is you can replace with  with jquery html() http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$("#notification").html('Error');
```

or fade at once like this;

```
$("#notification").hide().html('Error').fadeIn();
```